# Multiply a variable in pipe

Tags: r, pipe, magrittr

I'm new in pipes R. 
I have a dataframe like this

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
df = data.frame(a= c(1,2,3,4,5), b = c(3,4,5,6,7))
```

The result is

```
df_min = df %>% filter(a > 2) %$%  as.data.frame( cbind(a=a*10, b)) 
> df_min
   a b
1 30 5
2 40 6
3 50 7
```

Is there is a more convinient and shorter way instead of `%$%  as.data.frame( cbind(a=a*10, b))`?

Comment: `df %>% filter(a > 2) %>% mutate(a = a * 10)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shorter option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[a > 2, .(a = a * 10, b)]
```

Answer (score 1):

A more convenient way to do it is as follows:

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

df = data.frame(a= c(1,2,3,4,5), b = c(3,4,5,6,7))

df_min = df %>% filter(a>2) %>% mutate(a=a*10)

class(df_min)
df_min
```

You can read about `mutate` [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.6/topics/mutate) and [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/computing-and-adding-new-variables-to-a-data-frame-in-r)'s some examples